# BQ Ciclop or Horus bury the lower part of a model

Tags: calibration, scanning

After all calibrations the models are missing the lower about 10-15mm depending on their size and shape regardless of the value of Pattern Settings/Origin Distance in Horus which happens to be 21.5mm. Tried from 10 to 30mm with no changes in scanned point clouds. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the original:

[image]

And here's the scanned cloud:

[image]

Comment: Although the mission statement for this forum includes tools for 3d printing, this question appears to be quite some distance outside that scope, as it appears to be fully directed toward a scanning application and related problems.

Comment: @fred_dot_u - While I would agree, as there isn't currently a specific SE site for scanning, what other option does the OP have for posting their question, except here? Also, I guess, the scanning process does form part of the *overall* 3D printing process, even though it is more to do with *preparation* rather than *printing* per se. :-)

Comment: I agree that 3D scanning questions should be allowed.  Scanning is often associated with 3D printing and making this site narrower will make it even more difficult to exit Beta.